# Sort Wordpress Posts by One Custom Field , while excluding all with another value

Tags: php, wordpress

i have my wordpress posts with two custom fields
'episode_number'
'season_number'

i want to select all posts with season_number=5(example) , and sort them by episode_number DESC

i've written this

```
            $max_season=5;
            $args = array(
            'meta_key' => 'season_number',
            'meta_compare' =>'==',
            'meta_value' => $max_season,
            'orderby' => 'episode_number',
            'order' => 'DESC',
        );
$wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
```

the selection based on season_number works , but i can't order them , with this code wordpress order them based on the time of publishing

anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

My original answer was off the mark, I misread the question

Try something like this:

```
$max_season=5;
$args = array(
    'meta_key' => 'episode_number',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
        'key' => 'season_number',
        'value' => array($max_season),
        'compare' => 'IN',
        )
   )
);
$wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
```

Comment: This will only sort by the selected `meta_value` in numeric order, which is always 5 as per the OPs query.

Comment: You are right, apparently I didn't read the question thoroughly enough. *hangs head in shame*

Answer (score 0):

I believe WordPress will only query the specified metadata you requested, which is `key=season_number`, `value=5` (the season number). It will not query the post metadata for the key `episode_number`, so there is no way you can sort by that field directly in the SQL query.

You either need to loop the result of the query and get each item's metadata for `key=episode_number` and populate a new sorted array accordingly or figure out a way to query also this metadata in a single query as well.

For the second one, I have no idea how this will work.

Comment: something like



while($max_stagioni>0){
   
   $args = array(
            'meta_key' => 'numero_stagione',
   'meta_compare' =>'==',
   'meta_value' => $max_stagioni,
   'orderby' => 'numero_puntata',
   'order' => 'DESC',
        );
$wp_query = new WP_Query($args);

$args = array_merge( $wp_query->query_vars, array( 'meta_key' => 'numero_episodio' ,'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 'order' => 'DESC',) );
query_posts( $args );



?